# how to make Delphi tlistview work like explorer

Tags: delphi, windows-explorer, tlistview

Windows Explorer has some behaviors that I would like to replicate in a themed application for a Delphi TListView.

(This works fine if I don't have themes for the list view, but I'd rather have themes if at all possible)

In Windows Explorer, when I click in the white space around an icon I can still make a dragover box and when I right click I get the popup menu for the container, not the icon.

With themes on, the selection grows to the entire bounding box of the item in the list, with themes off it shrinks to fit the size of the text in the list item.

What do I need to do to have themes:

[image]

But keep them working like no themes?

[image]

and work like Windows Explorer (allowing drag when selecting part of the row that is highlighted)

[image]

Comment: Starting with windows vista, Windows explorer uses the undocumented DirectUIHWND class.

Comment: @RRUZ OK, so it won't be automatic, do you think it's possible?

Comment: Try adding a image to show what do you want to accomplish.

Comment: @RRUZ OK, the first image is what happens now, the second is what happens without themes (I like the behavior, I don't like the style) and the third is windows explorer where everything works exactly right (but since it's not even the same control isn't a very good example)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use [VirtualTreeView](http://www.lischke-online.de/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview) instead. It is a powerful component with a huge possibilities, so you can do what you want event if the themes are not available

Comment: VirtualTreeView is a fine component, but your answer doesn't answer the question, since it not only suggests a different component, but also doesn't show how to solve the problem using that component. It should rather be a comment.